# Woman wakes up on spaceship in garden, what is it from?

Tags: identify-this-movie

A while ago I saw a short episode about a woman waking up in a garden on a spaceship she remembers being home on earth and has no memory of what happened to her. The space ship seems to be on the fritz. She finds a man and I think he ends up dying.

I don't remember what the name of the episode or trailer was... I just remember she is trying to figure out what is going on. I am sure it isn't the Syfy series Continuum. Does anyone know what I am talking about?

I saw at trailer for it within the last two years. It may have been a web series and I only saw the first episode.

Comment: Probably not the same movie, but similar: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9834/1876

Comment: Could you add some more information, like when you watched it or provide some rough time frame. Everything that might help the identification, however small that detail may seem to you.

Comment: You know you're making me think of the Doctor Who episode Flesh and Stone, Amy wasn't asleep but she had her eyes closed and there's a conversation about not remembering what happened when she was a child...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The movie you are looking for is *Ark*; it is a short story by Sachs/Judah Productions. Here are the links to both Hulu and IMDb.

http://www.hulu.com/#!ark

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345784/companycredits?ref_=tt_dt_co

Comment: You found it! That was it. Thanks you rock and just made my day!

Answer (score 3):

This might be the opening scenes of [*Solaris* (1972)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069293/) by *Andrei Tarkovsky*.

Comment: Welcome to [movies.se] and thanks for your answer. Maybe you want to provide some explanations to support ity? And by the way, please try to adhere to at least a minimal structural form, for now I fixed this for you.

Answer (score 1):

It could be [Jason X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_X). The frozen bodies of Jason Vorheese and his victim are found in the future on earth and they take her to their spaceship. The team of spaceship wakes up the female victim and regenerate her damaged body-parts. But Jason wakes up himself and kills everybody one by one. They manage to confuse Jason by making a fake lake seen full of greenery but not for long.

Comment: The woman seems to wake up on her own. The spaceship appears abandoned like something bad had happened.

Answer (score 0):

[*Sunshine*](http://imdb.com/title/tt0448134/combined) maybe? It's got the abandoned spaceship, garden, dead and dying, etc.

Comment: Is this the one you mean? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/combined Please add the link to your answer.

Comment: I watched the trailer and it doesn't seem the same. The woman doesn't remember who she is and it seems like there are only two people on the ship.