# Strange and haunting Science Fiction Film

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

What is the name of this movie:

Possibly filmed in the 70's or 80's, sort of like the movie Silent Running in that it has a greenhouse filled with lots of plants. I only remember the ending of the movie where one man dressed in white stands alone in the spacecraft looking out through huge glass walls (I think like a dome) seeing only space and stars. I think the spacecraft is adrift, lost in space somehow. Anyway this man chooses to remain caring for the plants not really knowing where the craft is going. It is a very haunting tale.

Comment: Probably not the same movie, but similar: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9826/1876

Comment: This exactly like Silent Running - what makes you think it isn't the same film?

Comment: Gotta agree with Nobby, if you had not said 'like the movie Silent Running' I would have been 99% confident that it was that movie.

Comment: What makes you so sure it's not _Silent Running_?  While the ending is different, that scene you describe might be from earlier in the movie.  Also, are you sure it was a movie and not on a TV show?

Comment: Was there short robots in the film? Did they drive around in little go-carts? Did he play poker with the robots? Where there nuclear explosions?

Answer (score 3):

I put together the timeframe, spacesuit, and greenhouse to come up with this suggestion, a great movie - essentially [High Noon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044706/) in space.
I think you might mean [Outland](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082869/) from 1981, with Sean Connery. Connery plays a Marshall on an off-world mining colony, not a spaceship, who annoys the local company President, played by Peter Boyle. When the annoyances get too deep, since the President is involved in a conspiracy to increase profits, he hires an assassination team to deal with the marshall, Connery. The showdown scenes involve a hide-and-seek in the colony's massive glass greenhouse, which is hundreds of feet high and wide, multiple stories. Outside the glass, of course, is a starfield. The assassins are inside with Connery outside in a pressure suit.

Otherwise, I agree you mean [Silent Running](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067756), also.

Comment: Yeah - I thought about Outland (and even The Black Hole) while thinking about space-born greenhouses, but neither were as perfect a fit as Silent Running, which leaves me even more perplexed - LOL

Comment: Outland green houses were dark and grunge. The Black Hole had a kind of 2001 ending.

Comment: But there was a greenhouse in it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remember this old science fiction movie back in middle school and this question popped up. I actually found what it was, could it be "All Summer in a Day"? It's a short story by Ray Bradbury.

Comment: So does the movie you searched and found relate to the movie in this question? If yes, you might want to elaborate in which way it fits to the movie asked for here to flesh out the answer a little.